# Rust lifetime inference in constrainted impl with lifetime parameter fails, but tweaking the constraints resolves the error

Tags: rust

I'm working with some code that delegates some responsibility to another type which holds a reference to the "data" type. When I try and implement a trait the delegate implements for the data type, I hit a lifetime error I don't quite understand.

```rust
trait Converts<T> {
    fn convert(&mut self, from: T);
}

trait CompoundConversion<C> {
    fn convert(&self, to: &mut C);
}

struct TestThunk<'a> {
    test: &'a Test,
}

impl<'a, C> CompoundConversion<C> for TestThunk<'a> 
    where C: Converts<String> + Converts<isize>
{
    fn convert(&self, to: &mut C) {
        to.convert(self.test.name.to_owned());
        to.convert(self.test.id);
    }
}

struct Test {
    name: String,
    id: isize,
}

impl Test {
    fn thunk<'a>(&'a self) -> TestThunk<'a> {
        TestThunk {
            test: self
        }
    }
}

// Produces an error:
impl<'a, C> CompoundConversion<C> for Test 
    where TestThunk<'a>: CompoundConversion<C>
{
    fn convert(&self, to: &mut C) {
        self.thunk().convert(to)
    }
}
```

I think this doesn't work because `'a` is inferred to be valid for the lifetime of the `Test` value, rather than simply the method call.

What I'm really confused about though, is that changing the constraints slightly fixes it.

```rust
// Works:
impl<C> CompoundConversion<C> for Test 
    where C: Converts<String> + Converts<isize>
{
    fn convert(&self, to: &mut C) {
        self.thunk().convert(to)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5a15f15a489327e655558c7d3a1d129)

This builds without any issues, but the code isn't doing anything different. As far as I can tell, these two sets of constraints should be functionally identical, but clearly the presence of the lifetime parameter in the first example makes a difference somehow. When the explicit parameter is removed, the compiler seems to infer a lifetime that works but I have no idea if I can help it do that for the first example too.

What exactly is causing the first example to fail, even though a constraint that is effectively the same (but without the lifetime parameter) works fine?

Is there a way to make the first example work without resorting to duplicating the `Converts` constraints on both `Test`'s and `TestThunk`'s impls?

Comment: You can fix the first version by using an HRTB: `where for<'a> TestThunk<'a>: CompoundConversion<C>`

Comment: Declaring `'a` at the impl level basically let's the _caller_ choose this lifetime. You need to have the constraint for a lifetime the compiler can choose, though.

Comment: HRTB did the trick! I’m not sure why I didn’t think of trying that. 

Thank you!